# How to removing leading section in bash

Tags: string, bash

How can I remove parts of a string up to a certain character?

Ex.) If I have the string `testFile.txt.1` and `testFile.txt.12345` how can I remove the `1` and `12345`?

EDIT: I meant to remove and throw away the first part of a string up to a certain character and keep the end of it.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear - could you please clarify the "remove parts of a string up to a certain character?"; The example can be interpreted many ways and to be honest most of them are for "removing after a certain character" and not "up to".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

using just bash facilities

```
$ s=testFile.txt.1
$ echo ${s%.*}
testFile.txt

$ s=testFile.txt.12345
$ echo ${s%.*}
testFile.txt
```

to remove before leading zero

```
$ echo ${s#*.}
txt.12345
```

Other method, you can split your string up using IFS

```
$ s=testFile.txt.12345
$ IFS="."
$ set -- $s
$ echo $1
testFile
$ echo $2
txt
$ echo $3
12345
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove a known suffix from a filename, you can use `basename`:

```
basename testFile.txt.1 .1
basename testFile.txt.12345 .12345
```

Comment: Is there an elegant way to also remove that leading period in the same line?

I can do it in two, I was just curious...Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what leading period you're talking about

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed to do a search and replace. The `<<<` operator will pass in a string on stdin.

```
$ sed 's/\.[0-9]*$//' <<< "testFile.txt.1"
testFile.txt
$ sed 's/\.[0-9]*$//' <<< "testFile.txt.12345"
testFile.txt
```

Comment: note that if you're processing a lot of files, this will take noticeably longer than "pure bash" solutions if it launches a new process (`sed`) for each one.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear - the example provided may mean you want to remove all #s, or remove the part after the last ".", or remove the part after the first "1", or even remove all charcters after character 13. Please clarify.

If you mean that you want to remove first N characters in a string (e.g. "up to a character # 13"), do `echo testFile.txt.1 | cut -c14-`. To retain the chars 1-13, on the other hand, do `echo testFile.txt.1 | cut -c1-13`

If you mean that you want to remove the beginning characters until the first occurence of a specific character (in your example that seems to be "1"), do `echo testFile.txt.1 | perl -e 's/^[^1]*//;'`. To remove everything AFTER the first "1", do `echo testFile.txt.1 | perl -e 's/1.*$//;'`

If you want to remove all the #s, do `echo testFile.txt.1 | perl -e 's/\d//g;'` or without Perl, `echo testFile.txt.1 | tr -d "[0-9]"`

If you want to remove everything after the last ".", do `echo testFile.txt.1 | perl -e 's/\.[^.]+/./;'`

Answer (score 0):

```
# remove string prefix up to the first digit
var='testFile.txt.12345'
var='test1File.txt.12345'
var='testFile.txt.1'
var='testFile.txt'

echo "${var#"${var%%[[:digit:]]*}"}"
```