# Split string with bash with symbol

Tags: string, bash, sed, awk

For example, I have a string: `test1@test2`.

I need to get the `test2` part of this string. How can I do this with bash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String Manipulation in Bash . . . Removing leading section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680274/string-manipulation-in-bash-removing-leading-section)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Using [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02):

```
str='test1@test2'
echo "${str#*@}"
```

1. The `#` character says *Remove the smallest prefix of the expansion matching the pattern.*
2. The `%` character means *Remove the smallest suffix of the expansion matching the pattern.* (So you can do `"${str%@*}"` to get the `"test1"` part.)
3. The `/` character means *Remove the smallest and first substring of the expansion matching the following pattern.* Bash has it, but it's not POSIX.

If you double the pattern character it matches greedily.

1. `##` means *Remove the largest prefix of the expansion matching the pattern.*
2. `%%` means *Remove the largest suffix of the expansion matching the pattern.*
3. `//` means *Remove all substrings of the expansion matching the pattern.*

Answer (score 35):

```
echo "test1@test2" | awk -F "@" '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Or, in bash, `awk -F "@" '{print $2}' <<< "test1@test2"`

Comment: But this doesn't split the string, it just prints second part. You can't do in bash `for substring in "${awk -F '@' '{print $2}'[@]}"`.

Answer (score 10):

Another way in Bash:

```
IFS=@ read -r left right <<< "$string"
echo "$right"
```

Note that this technique also provides the first part of the string:

```
echo "$left"
```

Comment: You should recover IFS then to space: IFS=" ". Because bash uses IFS to parse command line parameters.

Comment: @StepanDyatkovskiy: `IFS` is only temporarily given a new value in the execution environment of `read`. This happens when a variable assignment precedes a command in this way.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "test1@test2" | sed 's/.*@//'
```

Comment: Or, in bash, `xxx="test1@test2"; sed 's/.*@//' <<< $x`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know what you mean here, but aren't you missing some `x`es?

Comment: Hmm...yes, it looks like 'dos equis' escaped.  It's a little late to be editing the comment...